# Convert data from email header

Tags: php, date-format, email-headers

Does anyone could help me how to convert data from email header?

I have the next date format from email header:
`Wed, 28 Apr 2010 21:59:49 -0400`

I need to convert them into mysql Date, or timestamp. Thanks!

Comment: I try parse this header manualy in loop, but I think it's not a good idea. I found strtotime, but can't understand how to use them for my case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) for this, specifically [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat):

```
$str = 'Wed, 28 Apr 2010 21:59:49 -0400';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'D, d M Y H:i:s O', $str);
```

Now, you have a Date object in `$date`, and you can grab the unix timestamp (if that's what you want), or you can format it into a date for MySQL.

```
echo $date->getTimestamp(); // Outputs: 1272506389
echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); // For MySQL column, 2010-04-28 21:59:49
```

You can see it working in [the demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ha8AjI).